# What's the "right" way to override a symfony extension from another bundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I need to override the file 
/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Extension/AssetsExtension.php

It loads the twig getAssetUrl from the bundle using the twig function 'asset'

```
/**
 * Returns a list of functions to add to the existing list.
 *
 * @return array An array of functions
 */
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('asset', array($this, 'getAssetUrl')),
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('assets_version', array($this, 'getAssetsVersion')),
    );
}
```

I want to override the asset() twig function without touching the core files, which otherwise would be overridden by the next symfony update

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider that your code live in AppBundle namespace. First create service configuration in app/config.yml or src/AppBundle/Resources/config/something.yml (you have to load this configuration file in [bundle extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html)). Don't forget place it under services key.

```
twig.extension.assets:
    class:     AppBundle\Twig\AssetsExtension
    arguments: ["@service_container", "@?router.request_context"]
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Now let's create extension src/AppBundle/Twig/AssetsExtension.php. This class inherits from original extension and I will override just one method (in template asset()).

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class AssetsExtension extends \Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Extension\AssetsExtension
{
    public function getAssetUrl($path, $packageName = null, $absolute = false, $version = null)
    {
        return parent::getAssetUrl('/something/' . $path, $packageName, $absolute, $version);
    }
}
```

Now, after reload, all your assets should be incorrect and prefixed with /something/ by default. You can try to delete Symfony cache in case of problems. I tested this scenario on Symfony 2.5.5.

Another way how to work with built-in services is [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html). In compiler pass you can modified whole Symfony service container (delete, replace, modify services). Symfony is all about DIC. I hope it is good enough solution.

Comment: Instead of duplicating the service definition you can also just set the parameter twig.extension.assets.class to point to the new extension class.  But the compiler pass is really the best solution.  Actually, I question the need for changing getAssertUrl at all.  Probably will cause more trouble than it's worth especially if you are using any 3rd party templates.  Consider just writing your own extension and function.

Comment: Yes, that's true. You can also set parameter twig.extension.assets.class with custom extension. The question was clear - how to override asset() without touching Symfony code. I really do not have a clue about use-case why user3531149 needs it.

Comment: Your solution is fine.  Hopefully this is not another drive by.

Answer (score 9):

I provide another solution, because since symfony 3.0 the services' class names are not overridable anymore.
You have to chose the compiler pass solution.

Let's say you want to override url() function in twig, you should create a compiler pass for it and change the definition :

```
<?php
// AppBundle/AppBundle.php

namespace AppBundle;

use AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\TwigRoutingExtensionPass;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new TwigRoutingExtensionPass());
    }
}
```

Then create the TwigRoutingExtensionPass file :

```
<?php
// AppBundle/DependencyInjectoin/Compiler/TwigRoutingExtensionPass.php    

namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use AppBundle\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;

class TwigRoutingExtensionPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (false === $container->hasDefinition('twig.extension.routing')) {
            return;
        }

        $definition = $container->getDefinition('twig.extension.routing');
        $definition->setClass(RoutingExtension::class);
    }
}
```

And then create your RoutingExtension file.

If you want to inject some services to the new extension :

```
<?php

    $definition->addArgument('some_service');
    // OR
    $definition->addMethodCall('setSomeService' [$container->get('some_service')]);
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, but I receive an error `The "Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\TranslationExtension" extension is not enabled in` in my case I'm trying to override the trans() function. any ideas ?

Comment: sorry but, have you enabled the translator ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#configuration

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to have a look at [Symfony's "decorate"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html)

```
# If it is a named service
My\CoreBundle\Twig\OverrideItWithThisExtension:
    decorates: 'some.other.twig_extension'

# If the service has a "FQCN"
My\CoreBundle\Twig\OverrideItWithThisExtension:
    decorates: Some\Other\TwigExtension
```

This way the original service actually still exists and you can still access it if you really want